# Is it possible to delete an item by taking one of the item in array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-material

I have used angular material modal window to confirm the delete an item from an ng-repeat created items, But i don't want to delete an item with the `index`, but i need to delete with help of `id`.

```
$scope.users = [{
  _id:'1',
  firstName: 'Obi-Wan',
  lastName: 'Kenobi'
 }, {
  _id:'2',
  firstName: 'Boba',
  lastName: 'Fett'
 }, {
  _id:'3',
  firstName: 'Han',
  lastName: 'Solo'
}];
```

I have used _id here, with the help of this id, i need to delete that particular item. 
 this is the plunker of deleting item with the help of index. i need it with the help of _id. Can anyone please help me. 
[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DWkSTZGsmWkFhrAQkYnv?p=preview)

Comment: why would you want to delete it with `_id` ? There is already a option available.

Comment: Because, i need to send the delete request to server, using id.

Comment: You have `user` object. you can use that to get `_id` and send `delete` request using that and delete object here using `spilce` as you used in your code.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/MEvoPyYtGEZ474GrToKe?p=preview
this is the updated plunker please check. i am getting id. but i am not able to delete that particular item. it is deleting another item.

Comment: In your `$scope.delete` function just console log. It is working. Console also shows me `user` object.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/B0bmsFw9fJjmg7SfyhCX  see It is deleteing proper object

Comment: i know it will delete the particular object with the index. but not when using id.
 i got your idea. deleting here using splice and sending request with id. but is this  a good way

Comment: Of course it is. You must be using `$http` to communicate to server. So there won't be any problem. and after all It is in you controller I think you can send `delete` request from there.

Comment: why did i asked is. one of my senior told that was a wrong way of doing. Any way thank you for your help. great

Comment: So what is the better solution then If you learn let me know.

Comment: he is telling to find the solution on my own. so i asked. thank you

Comment: cool. I'll let you know if I find something.

Comment: Refer http://plnkr.co/edit/o6G1dPD0WbwifJLa99U7?p=preview

Comment: @nextt1 . i got why he was telling like that. because if we directly delete with the splice method. it will show deleted to user in front end and not deleted in server due to some unknown issues in server. for this issue what to do

Comment: It would be very easy just use `$http`. It will return a promise So you will have 2 options. `success` or `fail`. so you can `splice` in your `success` method. Should I give an example for that ?

Comment: No, i got it. Thank you

Comment: It is accepted. to accept you didn't wrote answer. you are just commenting here. if you write an answer.  i will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as you have your `user` object in yout `delete` function as shown in you code you can delete that object using `splice` method and to send the `delete request` you can use `$http` service as below.

```
$scope.delete= function(user){
               $http.delete('/users/' + user._id, {params: {userId: user._id}})  
                    .then(function (response) {
                      if(response.status == 200){
                         var index = $scope.users.indexOf(user);
                         $scope.users.splice(index, 1);
                      }
               })
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. another doubt. how to fetch the id in custom dialog. please check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rETeNlIMbutvfN4ZRKZR?p=preview) . i am not able to fetch the id inside template as well as in console. can you please help me

Comment: I think It's seperate question. Can You ask it seperately ?

Comment: It is showing **You have reached your question limit**. so i can not ask another question. can you please help me here

Comment: I would love to help. But I need proper description as a question.

Comment: Thank you. please check https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7628 . if you couldn't understand , please let me know